# How do I add an Android .XML Vector Asset in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have several Android .XML Images, which supposedly loads faster.

In C#, how do I assign the XML file to an ImageSource.

Currently I have an example *phone.xml* file in the Drawable folder of my android project.

I try to call this:

```
var imgSource = ImageSource.FromFile("phone.xml");
```

but no image is displayed. Can I display an image directly from the drawable folder of the Android project?

Comment: are they svg files?

Comment: no. They are .xml files, created in Android Studio

Comment: Did you try “drawable/phone.xml”? Obviously you’d need to add a conditional statement so it uses that string only for android

Comment: @Saamer Oh wow... it works! Need to also set build action as 'AndroidResource'. Also 'drawable/phone' works too. Thanks. Do you want to add the answer? And I will put it as accepted answer to credit your reply

Comment: @user1034912 that's awesome! I'm glad you got it to work :)
What you can do is that you can dig into the Android project's generated temp bin and obj files to see the folder structure of how images get stored so you can understand why it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `drawable/phone.xml` and as you mentioned in your comment `drawable/phone`.

Obviously you’d need to add a [conditional statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/device) so it uses that string only for android:

```
string source = "phone.png";
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
    source = "drawable/phone"
var imgSource = ImageSource.FromFile(source);
```